# Prove that K is subgroup.

Tags: permutations

Let K be the set of all permutations of $ S_4 $ type $ [2 ^ 2] $ and the identity permutation $\in K $. Prove that $ K $ is a subgroup $  S_4 $.
I would like to prove that for$\pi, p \in S_4$ and type of $[2^2]$
$\pi p $ also is in K. But I can't deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the $24$ permutations in $S_4$ there are exactly $3$ permutations of the desired type. Write them explicitly, and then verify that if you multiply two of them you get the third.

The above shows that $K$ is closed under multiplication, to finish the argument that $K$ is a subgroup show that each of your $3$ non-trivial elements is its own inverse and thus $K$ is also closed under taking inverses.

Comment: yes, it's one solution but solve it in general way because the number can be much bigger.

Comment: What do you mean 'in a general way'? Your questions asks about $S_4$.

Comment: ok, but what if my question will be about $S_{99}$

Comment: Then that'd be *another* question @user180834...and then the set of all permutations of type $\;[2^2]\;$ is not even closed, and thus not a subgroup: $$(12)(34)\cdot(12)(35)=(354)$$

Comment: In that case, the claim is not true. For example take $(1,2)(3,4)$ and $(5,6)(7,8)$. The above two permutations are of type $2^2$, but their product is of type $2^4$.

Comment: help...
I wrote 3 permutations:
$(1 2)(1 3) , (1 2 ) (1 4), (1 3)(1 4)$
And then I compose $(1 2 )(1 3 )(1 2 ) (1 4 ) 
and multiply them doesn't give third. :(

Comment: The permutation $(1,2)(1,3)$ is not of type $2^2$, it is of type $3^1$ because in disjoint cycle notation it is $(1,2,3)$.